# WPF Autocompletebox - Only allowing it to display underneith text

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have setup the WPF toolkit Autocompletebox. However I want to limit it so the suggestion only appear in a list underneath the textbox (currently it goes above it)

my current WPF XAML is below

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10,5,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="Client" Width="80" />
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="clientAutoCompleteText" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="240" ValueMemberPath="Name"
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}" MinimumPrefixLength="4" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I haven't taken a look at what the autocompletetextbox is using underneath but if it's a popup like I suspect then this would normally be down to how Windows decides where to put it if the control in question is at the edge of a window much in the same way a context menu from a tray icon can switch the side it is displayed on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is possible because [How to: Set the Placement Property for a Popup or Tooltip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750577(v=vs.85).aspx) (which explains in more detail about positioning a popup) shows that it is consistent with what I stated above.  The popup will automatically try to realign itself so that it is visible on screen in the default modes.

You would have to completely override the Popup's basic class to make the location appear "offscreen" but then you would end up with a focus that isn't visible, which is not desirable.